# How can I place a dependency of a plugin DLL in a specific location relative to it, so that it's found during runtime?

Tags: c, windows, dll

I'm writing a program A.exe, which uses `LoadLibrary` to load an external DLL B.dll during runtime.

B.dll resides in a specific directory near A.exe, but not in the same directory as A.exe. A.exe knows where to find it during runtime.

B.dll is dynamically linked (by GCC, not during runtime) to another DLL, C.dll.

At runtime, things run successfully if they're setup like so:

```
myapp/
. . . . A.exe
. . . . C.dll
. . . . myplugins/
. . . . . . . . . B.dll
```

However, I'd like things to be set up like so:

```
myapp/
. . . . A.exe
. . . . myplugins/
. . . . . . . . . B.dll
. . . . . . . . . C.dll
```

In this setup, `LoadLibrary` fails when loading `B.dll` because it can't find its dependency `C.dll`, since it is not in the same directory as the host executable.

How can I make the preferred setup work, without `A.exe` or its build process knowing anything about C.dll? The idea is that B.dll is a plugin for A.exe, so A.exe knows where to find it. However it shouldn't have to know anything about C.dll. Only B.dll should know anything about C.dll.

Comment: [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order).

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks so much! This article forwarded me to the docs for LoadLibraryEx, which turns out has a flag for this *exact* requirement. I'm posting that as an answer. If you'd like to post it as answer yourself, let me know and I'll remove mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out WinAPI has a simple way to satisfy exactly this requirement!

Solution found in [docs for dynamic library search order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order) and docs for [`LoadLibraryEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryexa).

Instead of using `LoadLibrary`, we need to use `LoadLibraryEx`. As far as I understand the main difference between the two is that the latter takes an optional flags argument to customize what it does.

In the flags to `LoadLibraryEx` we can pass `LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR` to specify that when loading the DLL, only the directory it resides in should be looked for its dependencies. If we also want Windows to look in the regular search path, we can combine it with `LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DEFAULT_DIRS`.

Example:

```
HMODULE handle = LoadLibraryExA(
    path, NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DEFAULT_DIRS | LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR);
```

I might be inaccurate on the details, refer to said documentaion as needed.

Thanks to @IInspectable for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Alternatively, you can continue using `LoadLibrary()`, and simply call [`SetDllDirectory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setdlldirectoryw) or [`AddDllDirectory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-adddlldirectory) beforehand to add the `myplugins` folder to the calling process's default search paths.